# animate a canvas component

Tags: canvas, html5

I need to highlight a child canvas component inside the parent canvas component.
The parent canvas is a circle and the child canvas components are small circles inside it. I need to highlight these specific small circles when hovered over another components. How can I do this ?

## Canvas

```
  <canvas aura:id="Chart" id="radarCHart123" width="600" height="600"/>
```

## Function to draw Main circle in canvas

```
baseMap: function(cmp, evt, helper){

    var canvas = component.find("Chart").getElement();
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

   var radius = 270;
    var center_x = 290;
    var center_y = 290;

    var canvas = component.find("Chart").getElement();
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");


      context.fillStyle = "#3F84F9";
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(center_x,center_y,radius,0,2*Math.PI);
      context.closePath();
      context.fill();

      context.fillStyle = "blue";
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(center_x,center_y,radius/1.5,0,2*Math.PI);
      context.closePath();
      context.fill();

      context.fillStyle = "#1B24A3";
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(center_x,center_y,radius/3,0,2*Math.PI);
      context.closePath();
      context.fill();

   }
```

## Function to draw mini circles inside Main circle

```
  points : function(cmp, evt, helper){

    var canvas = component.find("Chart").getElement();
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    for(var i=0; i< obj.length; i++){
      // Some logic to get the co ordinates (x, y) and point_size
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(x, y, point_size, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        context.fillStyle = "yellow";
        context.fill(); 
        context.font = font_size;
        context.fillStyle = "black";
        context.fillText(label,x-7,y+2);

    }
```

I am new to canvas. So please bear if this question is very basic or repeated.

If I hover mouse over the name on the right, it should highlight (like colour change for example) the marked point in the chart on the left. I can get the required Id's on hover.
[image: Canvas Image]

Comment: You'll want to use events to communicate with the child components.

Comment: Thanks.. But how can I use css here on the circles ?

Comment: You wouldn't use CSS on a canvas. That said, if we had a visual of what you were trying to do, we could probably help you.

Comment: I have added an image. Hope its clear now..

Comment: Ah, so this is a follow up to [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/185513). You might have mentioned that for some context.

Comment: Yes :) .. Sorry about that..

Comment: I found it.. I just need to redraw the child canvas again in a different method when the mouse is on hover mode.  Its working now..